# Convert raw http response to Koa compatible object?

Tags: node.js, koa2

I have a basic HTTP server created with the Node's `http` module:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

I'm getting the `request` and `response` objects from this raw http server, but I need to use them with some pre-existing Koa middlewares, so I'm looking for something to make Koa read them and return me a `context` object I can use.

What I use right now is:

```
const contextCompat = context => ({
 cookies: { get: key => getCookies(context.request)[key] },
  request: context.request,
  state: {},
  throw: (status, message) => {
    throw new Error(status, message);
  },
});
```

But I would like, instead, to use the built-in Koa logic to wrap my raw context.

Does Koa expose something I can use?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just set up your server as a Koa server from the beginning the way the library is intended to be used?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party library that's not Koa-ready so I need this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a solution, which makes use of a private API (so it may break).

```
const app = new Koa();

// pass the http request and response objects here
const koaContext = app.createContext(request, response);
```